# When not to use java8 streams?

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, java-stream

I was just trying out a few code snippets and came across an observation where using simple for loop gave me better performance results compared to using java 8 stream. Now, I may have missed something in understanding these things. I need help understanding the difference. Adding my code below.

```
//Following takes almost 3ms

public int[] testPerf(int[] nums, int[] index) {
    List<Integer> arrayL = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i =0; i< index.length; i++){
        arrayL.add(index[i], nums[i]);
    }
    return arrayL.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
}

//Following takes almost 1ms

public int[] testPerf(int[] nums, int[] index) {
    List<Integer> arrayL = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i =0; i< index.length; i++){
        arrayL.add(index[i], nums[i]);
    }
    int [] result = new int[index.length];
    for(int i =0; i< index.length; i++){
        result[i] = arrayL.get(i);
    }
    return result;
}
```

**EDIT: START**

What am I trying to test? Injecting elements of nums at indexes specified by index array to form a final result.

```
Input: nums = [0,1,2,3,4], index = [0,1,2,2,1]
Output: [0,4,1,3,2]
Explanation:
nums       index     target
0            0        [0]
1            1        [0,1]
2            2        [0,1,2]
3            2        [0,1,3,2]
4            1        [0,4,1,3,2]
```

**EDIT: END**

Note that I have tested these with different inputs and tried arrays containing 2k+ elements but still the code with for loop gave me better performance.

Please guide what is it that makes the other code take more time?
Also point out to any references where I can learn when NOT to use java streams? (When not to overcomplicate? :) )

Comment: The first method should be one line `return Arrays.stream(nums).toArray();` - your code is not optimal. Second, microbenchmarks are notoriously difficult to perform correctly (and you have not included the test harness which has led you to conclude which is faster).

Comment: Stream is not guarantees better performance but can guarantees better code readability. You can look mapToInt underhood how it's implemented.

Comment: *"simple for loop gave me better performance results compared to using java 8 stream"* That will **almost always** be the case, because there is a pretty big overhead to using streams. Only if the work in the loop is heavy, and you enable parallel processing, will streams potentially outperform old-style loops.

Comment: You don't explain how have you tested performance. That's why your results can be incorrect. What look strange: 1) The methods contains not only the functions you compare, but additional code. 2) You are talking about 1ms, 3 ms. This is  the range below the test precision. Do for instance 10 tests each lasting around 1 minute. Remove big deviations. Then take average. Then you have more or less realistic comparison. Still, *for* can be faster. But then you will know the realistic picture.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch `return Arrays.stream(nums).toArray();` Really? Why not `return nums.clone();` since that would be the much faster version of the same result? --- And that still entirely ignores the `index` parameter, which is likely there for a reason.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Added what am I trying to test so that you can correlate why am I doing what I am doing in the code.

Comment: Streams might perform better. They are not guaranteed to. And 2000 elements is still **much** too small. Try 2 billion elements.

Comment: @Andreas I did ignore the index parameter, because (as originally posted) it looked entirely sequential (and like OP was passing the precise index for adding elements at the back).

Answer (score 2):

I use streams over loops (I use anything over loops), when I can, because 
streams a usually much easier to write without bugs, even in absence of tests, because of their declarative uniform syntax. For the same reason they are usually much easier to read for a non-author, even without thorough commenting. Also, streams are lazy (think "pull"), for loops are eager (think "push"). And being lazy is usually better.

Unfortunately, streams have (sometimes substantial) overhead, so need to pay attention when writing performance critical code, especially with collectors.

So, something like "use streams when you can and loops where you must".

Answer (score 1):

The goal of streams is to make the code compacter, better readable, to reduce boiler plate and thus to simplify the developer's work. The goal of streams is not to give performance gains. The performance in a specific case can differ from *for*. Also streams can take a bit more memory. But the result - how streams are converted to a byte code - can depend on JVM: Oracle JDK, Open JDK, IBM JDK, etc.

If you have strict requirements for memory and performance, then there is no ready answer. You should compare your productive code (not the example you show here) in both variants - with *for* and with *streams*, then choose what fits your strict requirements.

**But...**

But in the most applications now days the impact of the loops, no matter is it *for* or *streams*, on performance is **very low** compared to other operations like accessing database or calling some web services via network. Even if *for* would be x10 faster compared to *streams*, but database access takes 2 000 ms, you would not see real difference.

Where as difference in the code style can be essential. Developers can produce code that is better readable. When some developers in your team go to other projects and some new join your team and have to extend the existing code, they will need less time to understand such code. It is not that understanding *for* is hard :) But reading code with multiple *streams* feels to many developers naturals compared to the code with *for*.

There are a few special cases where streams are hard to apply, like loop over 2 or 3 collections simultaneously. In such case streams make not much sense, *for* is preferable.

But in general there are no rules when to use or not to use specific construct. You know that any *while* and *do - while* loop can be replaced with a *for* loop. But why Java has different types of loops? Because some of them can express the logic in particular cases in a better way that other the others. Same with streams. If you and your team don't feel comfortable with streams, you don't have to use them. Give them a try, use them over 3 months, then discuss within the team and decide if every developer in your project should use them as much as possible or should try to avoid.

Comment: You should compare streams performance with that of bare for-loops, as that's what they are there to abstract, not network interaction or even OS interaction. If you do that you will see that streams, as I wrote in my answer have overhead, which may or may not be critical based on what the code does.

Comment: @bobah: Performance was very important in 1990 or 2000. In the cloud better response times can be obtained by buying more CPU power (to some extent, of course). So performance is not the most important metric. As I wrote in my answer, readability and maintainability of the code is very important...

Comment: ... If extending and modifying the more performant and less readable code costs monthly 20,000 USD more, and less performant but well readable and maintainable code needs monthly 1,000 USD more for CPU to provide the same response times, the customers prefer the cheaper solution that gives the same result, means **less performant, but more maintainable** code. Just calculate the costs for both approaches in your particular case.

Comment: Performance is important ALWAYS. Because you always need to make a decision if you pay for it or not. Architecting a distributed system for cloud deployment is expensive, paying for running such system is a running cost that no investor would like, code written by a monkey will easily cost you 100x of the code written by someone who actually knows what (s)he is doing.

Comment: But thank you, because of people who think that performance is no longer important we will always have clients to sell our cloud infra to! :-D

Comment: No, performance is important NOT always. Always important are the **costs**. Performance improvement by 1% that increases development costs by 500% is obviously NOT important. Same about streams. If a customer has a choice between A) getting the same small response time by adding more CPU and keeping highly maintainable code for monthly 1,000 USD or B) getting more performant but unreadable non-maintainable code for monthly 20,000 USD, obviously customer will prefer the cheaper approach...

Comment: ... Many developers follow **dogmas** without asking any questions. Architects consider **context**: what is right in one context can be wrong in another context.

Comment: Agree, especially the ones whose only tools are ArrayList and ConcurrentHashMap and whose only deployment platform is “serverless”, because you can rip off your client more if you add “cloud” into the project spec early enough.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243952/discussion-between-mentallurg-and-bobah).